# How to refresh the parent page and post value from child window in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to refresh the parent page and post value from child window in javascript/jquery?

I have using `window.opener.location.reload();`to refresh the parent page, but I have no idea how can I also passing the post value `?name=test&age=28` while refreshing the parent page.

Answer (score 2):

try,

`window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href + "?name=test&age=28"`

This should reload the parent page with the added values.

Comment: Nice to works! thank

Answer (score 0):

You could set the window's `href` attribute.

e.g.

`window.opener.location.href += "?name=test&age=28"`

Depending on the browser you may or may not need to still include the reload code.